# Adding a local variable to downloaded MySQL Data with Models

Tags: ios, swift

I am using MySQL and PHP to download a restaurants menu but the user of the app should be able to add a certain amount to which item from the menu they want. Currently I am using a stepper to indicate the amount and adding that amount to a UserDefaults key which gets called when the menu is downloaded again.
This makes me have to download the menu again when I go to another viewController which sums up the order but I can't seem to filter out only them items which do have an amount.

What is a better way to add that amount to the downloaded data and how can I filter these items in my cart ViewController to only show and use the items which have an amount.

My current downloadModel, MenuModel, cellViewController (for the menu tableview) look like this:

MenuDownload.swift:

```
import UIKit

protocol MenuDownloadProtocol: class {
    func productsDownloaded(products: NSArray)
}

class MenuDownload: NSObject {

    //properties
    weak var delegate: MenuDownloadProtocol!
    

    func downloadProducts() {
        
 
        let urlPath = "http://server.com/download.php" // Fake URL obviously

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download data")
            }else {
                print("Menu downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }
            
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {
        
        var jsonResult = NSArray()
        
        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
            
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            
        }
        
        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let products = NSMutableArray()
        
        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {
            
            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
            
            let restomenu = MenuModel()
            
            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let product = jsonElement["product"] as? String,
                let price = jsonElement["price"] as? String,
                let info = jsonElement["info"] as? String,
                let imageurl = jsonElement["imageurl"] as? String
                
                
            {
                let productandprice = product + " " + "€" + price
                let quantityy = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: productandprice) as? String
                    restomenu.product = product
                    restomenu.price = price
                    restomenu.info = info
                    restomenu.imageurl = imageurl
                    restomenu.quantity = quantityy
 
            }
            
            products.add(restomenu)
           
            
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            
            self.delegate.productsDownloaded(products: products)
            
        })
    }

}


extension String {
    func chopPrefix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return substring(from: index(startIndex, offsetBy: count))
    }

    func chopSuffix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return substring(to: index(endIndex, offsetBy: -count))
    }
}
```

MenuModel.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MenuModel: NSObject {

    //properties
    
    var product: String?
    var price: String?
    var info: String?
    var imageurl: String?
    var quantity: String?
   
    
    
    //empty constructor
    
    override init()
    {
        
    }
    
    
    
    init(product: String, price: String, info: String, imageurl: String, quantity: String) {
        
        self.product = product
        self.price = price
        self.info = info
        self.imageurl = imageurl
        self.quantity = quantity
        
        
    }
    
    
    //prints object's current state
    
    override var description: String {
        return "product: \(String(describing: product)), price: \(String(describing: price)), info: \(String(describing: info)), imageurl: \(String(describing: imageurl)), quantity: \(String(describing: quantity))"
        
    }
    
}
```

tableViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit




class productTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var productLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var orderCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
       
    var amount: String?
    
    
    @IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        
        amount = Int(sender.value).description
        orderCount.text = amount
  //      let defaultkey = String(productLabel.text!)
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(amount, forKey: productLabel.text!)
        
        if amount == "0"
        
        {
            orderCount.isHidden = true
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: productLabel.text!)
        }
        else
        {
            orderCount.isHidden = false
        }
        
    }
    
  
 
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    
   
    
}
```

EDIT: after trying filtering options and many different ways I still haven't found how to fix this. I think I'm overthinking it too much.